# Sum values within 1 seconds of timestamp of current row

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have data in the following format

Input >

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3,4,5], 'groupings':['groupa','groupa','groupa','groupa','groupb'], 'timestamp':['yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:35.111','yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:45.111','yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:30.111','yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:35.411','yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:35.211']})
```

Output >

```
    groupings   timestamp   value
0   groupa  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:35.111 1
1   groupa  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:45.111 2
2   groupa  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:30.111 3
3   groupa  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:35.411 4
4   groupb  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:35.211 5
```

I would like to create another column sum all the value within 1 second of the timestamp, in the same group,
For example

```
    groupings   timestamp         value  sum
0   groupa  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:35.111 1     5
1   groupa  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:45.111 2     2
2   groupa  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:30.111 3     3
3   groupa  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:35.411 4     5
4   groupb  yyyy-mm-dd 00:16:35.211 5     5
```

How should I go to achieve this?
Thank you in advance,

EDIT:
To be clear, I don't mean simply sum of all values of that exact second. For example, a value at 00:16:34.899 is still in within 1 second of 00:16:35.011.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've created a column by seconds and group by that column, and sum the value. However, what I'm concerning about is the case I mentioned in EDIT, which a value occured on 00:16:34.899 is still within 1 second of another value at 00:16:35.011, but won't be recorded the way I'm currently tackling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this copying `dataframe` as a new `df` variable, and at `df` make `'timestamp'` column all seconds of each datetime, then make a new column `'sum'` in `dataframe`, and make it the sum of each group `'value'` column of the groupby:

```
df=dataframe.copy()
df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.split().apply(lambda x: x[-1])).dt.second
dataframe['sum']=df.groupby(['groupings','timestamp'])['value'].transform('sum')
```

**Update:**

I finally got it working as expected:

```
df=dataframe.copy()
df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.split().apply(lambda x: x[-1]))
threshold = pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
dataframe['sum'] = df.groupby('groupings',as_index=False).apply(lambda df: [df.loc[(df['timestamp'] - t).abs() < threshold, 'value'].sum()
             for t in df['timestamp']])
dataframe['sum']=[x for i in dataframe['sum'].fillna('').tolist() for x in i]
```

Now:

```
print(dataframe)
```

Is desired output.

Comment: Thank you, I actually already tried this. However, the issue is, for example, a value at 00:16:01.944 is still within 1 second of another value at 00:16:02.011, and this is where I'm currently stuck.

Comment: @Linh Sorry for late reply, got back to my computer, gonna try to fix.

Comment: @Linh Wow, this is very hard.

Comment: It is a difficult issue. But I've tried a different approach and I think I can produce a good result anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @Linh Remember to accept if it works, also, i got a working solution for you now for that issue!!!, i'll add it to the post!

Comment: Sorry would you mind showing me how can I adapt for only counting value of the same grouping?

Comment: @Linh IIUC: Last line should be replace with `dataframe['sum'] = [df.loc[(df['timestamp'] - t).abs() < threshold, 'value'].size()
             for t in df['timestamp']]`

Comment: I mean each row has a category of either groupA or groupB and I would like to adapt so it only counts the rows of the same group only.

Comment: @Linh Got back to mu computer and edited mine, remember to accept if it works :-)

Comment: thank you. Actually, the edit would simply copy the sum value down all the rows indiscriminately, and would cause inaccuracies if groupa and groupb are intertwined in the data.

I've edited your last line with this code and everything seems to work:
`groupa_sum = dataframe.loc[0, 'sum'];
groupb_sum = dataframe.loc[1, 'sum'];
dataframe.loc[dataframe['groupings'] == 'groupa','sum'] = groupa_sum;
dataframe.loc[dataframe['groupings'] == 'groupb', 'sum'] = groupb_sum;`

Thank you

Comment: @Linh So happy to help after all this conversation, :-), 

Comment: :D I learned a lot from the way you tackled the issue as well ~ So job well done